# Как создать подобную структуру json из Питона?

Tags: python, json

Есть файл .json. В нём есть структура данных типа двух пар, то есть

```
user1 = {
   {
   "login": "login"
   "password": "pw"
   }
}
```

Как из .py-файла создать в этом .json подобную этой структуру? То есть, например, то же самое, но с user2.

Comment: Можете считать JSON используя встроенные возможности языка, можете создать класс/словарь или даже функцию, которая будет создавать нужный объект/словарь... Вариантов масса, в чём задача-то?

Comment: Советую изучить модуль tinydb, он работает с json базами данных.

Comment: @AivanF. , задача описана в вопросе. А проблема в том, что в json'e вообще не шарю.

Comment: Json это тот-же словарь в питоне

Comment: Кстати, Ваш "JSON" невалиден.

Comment: @nomnoms12, спасибо, а как теперь проверять схожесть строки в Python со строкой в json?

Comment: @EXTERMINATED Можете привести какой-то пример? Не до конца понимаю Вас.

Comment: @nomnoms12 . Если короче, то я пишу систему регистрации и входа по имени пользователя и паролю, которые в свою очередь хранятся в json-БД. Ну так вот, юзер зарегистрировался и захотел войти. Он вводит логин и пароль, а мне нужно проверять, есть ли данные в json'e.

Comment: @EXTERMINATED Тогда поступайте наоборот — `JSON` из файла преобразуйте в `Python`-объект с помощью функции [`loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) и проверяйте средствами языка. А вообще советую отказаться от _"json-БД"_ и использовать что-то понадёжнее (например, `SQLite`).

Answer (score 2):

Для работы с `JSON` есть [стандартный одноимённый модуль](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json).

Для конвертации `Python`-объекта в `JSON`-строку есть функция [`dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps).

***Пример:***

```py
import json

user2 = {
   'login': 'login',
   'password': 'pw',
}
json_string = json.dumps(user2)
print(json_string)
```

***stdout:***

```py
{"login": "login", "password": "pw"}
```